# NSDateFormatter will not work for the date before 1970?

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

```
double seconds = -62167464057.000;
NSDate *oldDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];
MELog("oldDate = %@", oldDate);//oldDate = 0002-12-29 03:59:03 +0000

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]  autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:oldDate];
NSLog(@"formattedDateString = %@", formattedDateString);//formattedDateString = 3:57 AM
```

In the above code, the date component has the time 3:59,  But when we format it to extract the time field, we are getting 3:57

My timezone is London, so it should return 3:59

Is this because of we are trying to format a date before 1970 ?  Please confirm if anyone knows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's exactly the reason. It is because of the "beginning" of timestamp:

```
Unix time, the number of seconds since 00:00:00 UTC on January 1, 1970
```

More [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp).

Answer (score -5):

IN YOUR CODE YOU ARE SETTING THE TIME INTERVAL TO 1970 .IT MIGHT BE BECAUSE OF THAT.TRY NOT TO USE THAT AND SET THE MINIMUM DATE BY URSELF.